# Connecting to Redis server in Windows 10 ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am having trouble connecting to Redis in my rails app on windows 10, and I added Redis to my gem file and setup my cable.yml file. The error that I am getting when I start my rails server is `rescue in establish_connection': Timed out connecting to Redis on localhost:6379` how do I fix this problem.

cable.yml

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

---

commandline

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:318:in `rescue in establish_connection': Timed out connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Redis::CannotConnectError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:311:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:91:in `block in connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:273:in `with_reconnect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:90:in `connect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:256:in `with_socket_timeout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:267:in `without_socket_timeout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:122:in `call_loop'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:35:in `subscription'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:12:in `subscribe'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:2587:in `_subscription'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:2008:in `block in subscribe'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:2007:in `subscribe'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:75:in `block in listen'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis/client.rb:273:in `with_reconnect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:43:in `block in with_reconnect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:42:in `with_reconnect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.0/lib/redis.rb:49:in `without_reconnect'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:72:in `listen'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:146:in `block in ensure_listener_running'

C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\ruby\chat>
```

Comment: Does the [`redis-cli` command-line tool](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) work?

Comment: @tadman yes its works

Comment: @tadman what a good way to test if server running in redis-cli

Comment: If it can connect and `INFO` gives the right details then it means your server is at least alive and accepting connections. The next step is to see why your Ruby code isn't connecting. I'd omit the port number if you're using the default, as often that can be mis-interpreted.

Comment: @tadman ok i see my detail about my server

Comment: Check if your configuration is for development, check if redis is running, also check if you have permission or firewall rules, sometimes  is run few rules for connection in your SO.

Comment: @jmike `localhost` is sometimes not configured. try using `url: redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1`

Answer (score 3):

Well, I had the same issue and it's working for me with this `cable.yml` config:

```
development:
  adapter: async
```

The crazy thing is that it's actually connecting to my local redis server! I guess that it shouldn't use redis at all with that config, but it's using it and it's working just fine.

Instead, if I set what I thought was the correct configuration, it fails:

```
development:
  :adapter: redis
  :url: redis://localhost:6379/
```

This is the error:

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:345:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError) (Redis::CannotConnectError)

So, I'm not sure **why**, and would be great if someone can explain it, but `adapter: async` solved it for me (Rails 5.0.7, Windows 10, redis gem 3.3.3).

Comment: That works for me, too. Ubuntu 18.04 rails 6.1.4.1